# If I register multiple listeners on a Firebase document, will it charge me for multiple reads of the same snapshot?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document I want to listen to for several different components, but it is cleaner to just register a listener for each component rather than register a "master" listener object and pass it around. Am I going to be charged per listener, or the same as if I only had one listener? Not sure if there is one Firebase connection that dispatches to all of the callbacks or if this opens up multiple websocket connections or whatever.

Comment: From my understanding Firestore will charge for each read regardless of its from the same app so you would be charged for each of your reads. I believe they even recommend pulling as much as possible and then execute as much client side as you can. They even charge for reads required in the security rules so if you’re budget conscious you should also pay attention to that. Check out the Firestore YouTube video (the official), I cant remember which one but they have one that goes over how Firestore charges.

Comment: As an example I store my client logs in Firestore but I upload all the logs at once as a single request as well as pull them all with a single request and then do my filtering etc client side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are charged for reads (or checks) that happen on the server.

If you have two listeners active, at most one of those will need to get the data from the server. The second listener will be able to read it from the cache.

If you use `get()` calls instead of listeners, the result is different. Since there is no active listener when using `get()`, the document may be changed in between the calls, and each call will have to check with the server whether there are updates to the data, resulting in a charged read.