# Does firestore treat same path snapshot listeners as same to server?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say If i have two sanpshot listener on the same path listening on client:

```
// First one
db.collection("testCollection").onSnapshot(function(doc) {}); 
// Second one
db.collection("testCollection").onSnapshot(function(doc) {});
```

Does sdk only connect one listener to server? Or still two to the server? Because the best practice says:

> Keep the number of snapshot listeners per client under 100.

I want to keep the number as low as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these two listeners exist in the same client, the SDK deduplicates then and attaches only one listener on the server.

Also see:

- [If I register multiple listeners on a Firebase document, will it charge me for multiple reads of the same snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813447/if-i-register-multiple-listeners-on-a-firebase-document-will-it-charge-me-for-m)