# Does firestore treat same collection snapshot listeners as same to server?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I asked this [Does Firestore treat same path snapshot listeners as the same to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783453/does-firestore-treat-same-path-snapshot-listeners-as-same-to-server) days ago, But I have another question, How if they are listening to the same collection of documents but not exactly the same query? Like:

```
// First one
db.collection("testCollection").orderBy('time').limitToLast(100).onSnapshot(function(doc) {}); 
// Second one
db.collection("testCollection").orderBy('time').limitToLast(20).onSnapshot(function(doc) {});
```

The second listener is listening in a range of the first one, Does Firestore connect the second listener to the server or just get data from the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the first listener, you'll have to pay 100 reads. When you attach the second listener to the same query but you're limiting the results to only 20, then you'll don't have to pay 20 reads, since those 20 documents are already in the cache.

So if you have those two listeners active on the exact same client, the first listener will get the data from the server, while the second listener will be able to read the data from the cache.

Comment: Does firestore only connect one listener of that to server? Because the best practice says  `Keep the number of snapshot listeners per client under 100.`, I want keep this number as low as possible.

Comment: The answer exists right inside Frank's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783453/does-firestore-treat-same-path-snapshot-listeners-as-same-to-server).